# how to get no. of live nodes IN HADOOP cluster in mapreduce program using java

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

in terminal it will shows no of live nodes with following command:

```
hadoop dfsadmin --report
```

we have tried this code....

```java
FSNamesystem fs=FSNamesystem.getFSNamesystem();
String s=fs.getFSState();
System.out.println(s+"\n\n");
```

in java mapreduce program how to get no of live nodes?

Answer (score 1):

From MapReduce job you can use following code:

```
YarnClient client = YarnClient.createYarnClient();
Configuration config = context.getConfiguration();
client.init(new YarnConfiguration(config));
client.start();
try {
    List<NodeReport> reports = client.getNodeReports(NodeState.RUNNING);
    System.out.println(reports.size());
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}
client.stop();
```

If you want to get not only live nodes you can change or add more node states at `client.getNodeReports()` method.